# Can I create column with header name according to values in another table?

Tags: sql-server

This is my first question here and please excuse me, if my question looks wired. I am totally new to programming and SQL though I have some knowledge in ms access database.

I have created two tables `OrdersTabel` and `OrderedItems`. Then I want to create another table `OrderFullDetails` as in the screenshot here:

[image: table Picture]

I want to create `OrderFullDetails` table as follows.

1. Contains in `Item` column in `OrderedItem` table should create separate column in `OrderFullDetails` table by its names.
2. If a column already exists in `OrderFullDetails` table equal to Item name in `OrderedItem` table, only the `Qty` value should be entered to the matching column according to OrderNo. And if there is no column matching, it should create a new column.

Your help will be million worth to me.

Thanks

Comment: You are looking for a PIVOT() it seems. Try this out. There are a lot of examples on stack overflow and the net. Specifically you will likely want to use dynamic SQL if there are more items than what is in your example. Here's a great reference. http://sqlhints.com/2014/03/18/dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server/

Comment: @scsimon, Thank you so much for you quick respond, I will go through what you suggested me and will get bake to you. thanks again.

Comment: No worries. Be sure to post your code if you try it but run into road blocks / errors.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 2):

Firstly welcome to Stack Overflow.  Normally in asking a question you are expected to show how you have attempted to solve the problem yourself.  Also we do not like pictures, and prefer to be given some sample data, in a format that makes it easy for us to copy. Please note that SO is not a coding service.  However, because it is your first time, I will be kind.

It goes against the normal rules of relational database design to build a third table to hold data that is already held in other tables.  What you should do is create a stored procedure to retrieve the records from both tables in a format that you want.  As scsimon rightly says you need a PIVOT and some dynamic sql in this procedure.

By way of example I give the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE OrderExample 
AS

CREATE TABLE #OrdersTable(
OrderNo int,
OrderDate date,
CustomerID int,
TotalItems int,
TotalAmount decimal(10,2)
)
INSERT INTO #OrdersTable VALUES(101, '2016-8-11', 354, 3, 30)
INSERT INTO #OrdersTable VALUES(102, '2016-8-12', 221, 2, 20)
INSERT INTO #OrdersTable VALUES(103, '2016-8-13', 67, 1, 20)
INSERT INTO #OrdersTable VALUES(104, '2016-8-14', 8965, 3, 40)

CREATE table #OrderedItems (
OrderNo int,
OrderItem varchar(10),
OrderQty int
)
INSERT INTO #OrderedItems VALUES(101, 'T-Shirt', 2)
INSERT INTO #OrderedItems VALUES(101, 'Bedsheet', 1)
INSERT INTO #OrderedItems VALUES(102, 'Pants', 2)
INSERT INTO #OrderedItems VALUES(103, 'Quilt', 1)
INSERT INTO #OrderedItems VALUES(104, 'T-Shirt', 2)
INSERT INTO #OrderedItems VALUES(104, 'Pants', 1)

DECLARE @itemNames varchar(max) = 
(SELECT  STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(OrderItem)
FROM #OrderedItems FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS ColList)


DECLARE @sql varchar(max) = 'SELECT OrderNo, OrderDate, CustomerID, 
TotalItems, TotalAmount,' + @itemNames + ' FROM
(SELECT o.OrderNo, o.OrderDate, o.CustomerID, o.TotalItems, o.TotalAmount,
i.OrderItem, i.OrderQty 
FROM #OrdersTable o
INNER JOIN #OrderedItems i ON i.OrderNo = o.OrderNo) SubQ
PIVOT(SUM(OrderQty) FOR OrderItem IN (' + @itemNames + ')) as pvt'

exec (@sql)

DROP TABLE #OrdersTable
DROP TABLE #OrderedItems
```

To run this, simply type: exec OrderExample

The result will be

```
OrderNo OrderDate   CustomerID  TotalItems  TotalAmount Bedsheet    Pants   Quilt   T-Shirt
101     2016-08-11  354         3           30.00       1           NULL    NULL    2
102     2016-08-12  221         2           20.00       NULL        2       NULL    NULL
103     2016-08-13  67          1           20.00       NULL        NULL        1   NULL
104     2016-08-14  8965        3           40.00       NULL        1       NULL    2
```

Note that in your finished version you will not need the lines that create the temporary tables, insert data and then finally drop them again.  Instead you must replace the #OrdersTable and #OrderedItems with the names of your correct tables (and of course the correct field names).  I have only included them, so that the example runs as a stand-alone.

Comment: @Chris I am using dynamic sql? The STUFF function is being used to get all item names via SELECT DISTINCT on the OrderedItem table. The values are not hard coded. So I do not understand why this will not work if more items are added. If I have done something wrong, please can you correct me.

Comment: Oh, shoot... I misread your answer (saw the sample data you were inserting and made a too-quick assumption that it was defining the columns).  Please disregard my comment.  I upvoted your answer.

Comment: @Chris Steele Thanks it was late in the evening for me, and I thought for a moment I was going mad.

Comment: Thank you @user6638270 for your guide and for being kind enough to write all codes for me. as you said, I will do when asking a question next time. tnx